# Fire notification at every 24 hours and at exact time of 8 AM

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using `AlarmManager()` to fire notification and repeat it at every 24 hours.

My code is on `onCreate()` in Splash Activity which fires first when anyone opens App. User can install App at anytime. So I want that when User installs App, It checks for the timing and then fires Notification at 8 AM and repeat it daily. I don't want notification when anyone opens App.

My code is as below :

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

final String WebsiteURL = "http://www.mytestbuddy.com";

String cookie;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle showSplash) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(showSplash);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cm.setAcceptCookie(true);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    if (cm.getCookie("" + WebsiteURL + "") != null) {
        cookie = cm.getCookie("" + WebsiteURL + "").toString();
    } else {
        cookie = null;
    }

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (cookie == null) {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "com.MobileWeb.mytestbuddy.Login");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                } else if (cookie.contains("Premium")) {

                    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
                    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
                    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

                    if (intendedTime >= currentTime) {
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                                intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);

                    } else {
                        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                                intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);
                    }

                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "com.MobileWeb.mytestbuddy.PremiumMain");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                } else {

                    Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
                    firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                    firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                    long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
                    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

                    if (intendedTime >= currentTime) {
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                                intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);

                    } else {
                        firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                                intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                                pendingIntent);
                    }

                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "com.MobileWeb.mytestbuddy.Main");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: The title should be like "Repeat Notification every day on specific time in Android with" so If any one google it and find it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do as chintan suggested. To get a clear picture, the `exact solution` might look something similar to the below:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar firingCal= Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8); // At the hour you wanna fire
firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second

long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

if(intendedTime >= currentTime){ 
   // you can add buffer time too here to ignore some small differences in milliseconds
   // set from today
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
} else{
   // set from next day
   // you might consider using calendar.add() for adding one day to the current day
   firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: well, I am very new to android development and this notification is giving me headache. Should I copy paste my code directly in else part or what ??? Please tell me.

Comment: @JeetenParmar You have got any issues? If so, post back. BTW you might need to accept one of our answers, if it helped you.

Comment: when i assign HOUR - 15, MINUTE - 50 in firingCal.set. It dint fire notification, but when i set it as hour - 3, it fired. mobile timing is 12 hours based. Timing set is based on user. So what to do for that ?

Comment: What do you mean by 15? Actually the milliseconds are used in setting an alarm with alarm manager. Or please elaborate it clearly.

Comment: @Appu... your code worked fine. But I got notification 3 times. What to do for it ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar Post back your full code by editing your question.

Comment: I don't think I have found any flaw in your code but some redundancy. When do you get notification 3 times? Did you debug your code?

Comment: it was nite time. and next day, i dint get any notification. I want to fire notification daily.

Comment: Use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead of Calendar.HOUR if you are setting it in 24 hour format.

Comment: But where is notification message I also want to do same thing please explain

Answer (score 10):

Here is pseudocode   :

You have to write this code inside your `Splash.java`

**Step 1 :** `Is_Alarm_Set();` [Boolean]

**Step 2 :** `false` [step 3]

**Step 2 :** `true` [step 8] (No need to set)

**Step 3 :** `Get_Time()` [User's Current Mobile Time]

**Step 4 :** `Find_Time_Difference()` [This function will find difference between user's mobile time and your Fix Time (8AM).]

**Step 5 :** Now set your alarm as per time difference.[i.e current time is 7 pm and date is 1-june then set alarm of 8 AM for next day.]

**Step 6 :** Set your repetition days [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

**Step 7 :** It will fire alarm as per your fix time 8 AM.

**Step 8 :** Switch Your Activity.

Comment: Please add Code with your answer, then it would be more suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Appu answer helped me a lot but if you want a fixed version of it a bit more readable and shorted look at this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar firingCal= Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8); // At the hour you wanna fire
firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second

if(firingCal.compareTo(currentCal) < 0) { 
   firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
} 
Long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(HomeContactActivity.this,
                    AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    HomeContactActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            // Set the alarm to start at 10:00 AM
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);




            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, // for repeating
                                                            // in every 24
                                                            // hours
                    pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Instead of using 86400000, using AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY is better.

Comment: i used the same above code but alaram is not triggering on current date ..if i change the date it triggers..i have posted question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577574/alarm-is-not-triggering-on-the-same-date