# Android Reminder Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Fairly new to java/android but getting better slowly.  I am trying to create a one time notification to remind the user about the app 24 hours after first run.  I researched online and using stackoverflow, I was finally able to get the code to run with the following notification code:

```
private void  addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
         .setContentText("This is a test notification");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

I am trying to call the notification function but it is not working.  I am calling it as follows:

```
addNotification();
```

How do I proceed from here? I have not dealt with the 24 hr issue, just trying to get the notification to come up. Then upon clicking it, the app should start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

You need to pass two parameters to `addNotification(Context context, String Message)`.

Like `addNotification(this,"My  Notification");`

```
private void addNotification(Context context, String message) {

  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
   .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  Notification notification;
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
  new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);


  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
  context);
  notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
 .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
 .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
 .setContentText(message).build();

  notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);

  }
```

For reminder you can implement **AlarmManager** or **Timer**.

- Alarm Manager : [Android Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- Timer : [Android Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Check these examples :

- http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/status-bar-notification-example-in.html
- http://androidexample.com/Create_Notification_Alert_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=102&aaid=124
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: Thanks.  I copied and pasted your code.  When I added addNotification(this,"My Notification"); I got an error : duplicate method.  ideas?

Comment: You need to remove your code for "addNotification" and add my code.

Comment: I removed my code.  and added yours.  What I have is your code and calling it using    addNotification(this,"My Notification");

Comment: I can't run it since there is an error so nothing new in Logcat.

Comment: not sure how to proceed.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Check my answer..I have added the example links..Hope this helps

Comment: I notice the "long when" is never used.  Can you help me to use it to set the notification to be 24 hours from the time the app is run.  Thanks.

Comment: You can implement AlarmManager for that.

Comment: This link might be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870781/fire-notification-at-every-24-hours-and-at-exact-time-of-8-am