# I want to start a service on the basis of real time

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which I want start a service at exactly 11:00am without user interaction. Is it possible?

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    // formattedDate have current date/time
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // Now we display formattedDate value in TextView
    TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
    txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
    txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtView.setTextSize(20);
    setContentView(txtView);
}
```

I have tried this code to fetch the real time but it's not for API's less than 25.

Comment: use alarm manager

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870781/fire-notification-at-every-24-hours-and-at-exact-time-of-8-am

Comment: Use alarm manager with broadcaset receiver and fire service form there

Comment: Some good reading on this: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I just fixed some minor grammar errors and fixed the formatting of your first line of code. Just keep in mind that "I" as a word should always be capitalized. Also note that you don't need to include "please help" and similar phrases; it's assumed you need help and a solution.